# Why isn't a color profile showing up in the Color Sync Utility (Mac OS 10.9.5)?

Tags: mac, colors

I'm trying to use a color profile, which isn't showing up in the Color Sync Utility despite being present in ~/Library/ColorSync/Profiles alongside other profiles that are showing up. When I open the file, Color Sync Utility opens its info window, but I can't see it listed as an installed profile. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There are several types of icc profiles; those for displays, those for RGB printers and those for CMYK devices (Presses, some PostScript printers etc).
If your icc profile does not show, it is possible intended for a colorspace that differs from what you need.